# kubectl diff doesn't show difference for directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I noticed a really strange bug with `kubectl diff` command.

I have a directory `k8s-test/` and when I run `kubectl diff -f k8s-test/` output is empty, but when I do `kubectl diff -f k8s-test/deployment.yaml` I can see the differences for that specific file in the output.

How can I debug this to find out the root cause?

Comment: if its a bug, you should file an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `kubectl diff --recursive -f k8s-test`